# mark only one checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with checkbox. I have a list of checkbox, and I  want to mark only one check and unmark other.

I want do that this  in the same view , is it posible?
How can I do that?

```
<div><input  type="checkbox" id="<%= id %>"  onchange='submit();'/> </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use radio buttons, not checkboxes.

```
<div>
    foreach (var foo in model.Foos) {
        <input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo_@foo.Id" value="@foo.Id" /> 
        <label for="foo_@foo.Id">@foo.Value</label> <br />
    }
</div>
```

Something like that should create a list of radio buttons.

Also, why are you submitting when the selection is changed? You should be using jQuery to do any selection-based manipulation to the page on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you really need a radio button instead. Radio buttons are mutually exclusive if you give them the same name:

```
<input  type="radio" name="something" ... />
<input  type="radio" name="something" ... />
```

If you really want checkboxes you will have to write some JavaScript logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery. on document.Ready you'll have to bind a change event on checkboxes to some function, then in your function you want to reset all other checkboxes. That's assuming you don't want to use radio buttons as suggested above.